# testing rxjs catchError and subscribe scenarios in jest and Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, ts-jest

I have the following piece of code I want to test:

```js
someAction(ids: string[]): void {
    this.testService
      .someActionFromService(ids)
      .pipe(
        catchError((error) => {
          this.close(); // component method
          return throwError(() => error);
        }),
      )
      .subscribe(() => {
    this.close();
        // call other component methods
      });
  }
```

For testing, I am using the following:

```js
describe('someAction(): ', () => {
    it('des', fakeAsync(() => {
      fixture.detectChanges();
      const testServiceSpy = testService.someActionFromService.mockReturnValue(new Observable()); // the service has been mocked properly earlier
      const closeSpy = jest.spyOn(component, 'close');
      component.someAction(['id1']);
      fixture.detectChanges();
      tick(1000);
      fixture.detectChanges();
      expect(testServiceSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['id1']);
    // Works fine till here
    // following throws an error
      expect(closeSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    }));
  });
```

The error thrown is as follows:

```js
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()

    Expected number of calls: >= 1
    Received number of calls:    0
```

The issue is that my tests aren't reaching within `catchError` or `subscribe`.

Please help with regards to what can be done here to make the tests successful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.mockReturnValue(new Observable())` is not the thing that you want. it is basically `NEVER` - the observable that never emits a value and never completes.

what you want is `.mockReturnValue(of(goodValue))` for positive scenario or
`.mockReturnValue(throwError(new Error('some error')))` for the negative one